# How do you use Kontakt Player with Sibelius - program?

Tags: software

There are some questions about Sibelius 7 which have been approved, so I dare to ask this question on relationship between Kontakt player( trial version) and Sibelius 7:
How do you use Kontakt Player with Sibelius - program? I have Kontakt Player ( trial- version) and I don't get any other sound but just piano. And I'm wondering in which way you use this program. Can it playback sibelius - files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sibelius 7, to use Kontakt, you have to create and configure a custom set of playback devices (VST or AU virtual instruments or similar). Under the **Play** tab, select **Setup**, and this pulls up the **Playback Devices** dialog box, where you can specific Kontakt as a source if it is installed on your system.

[image]

Comment: This is good as far as it goes, but to really utilize all the features, you must create a sound set for the Kontakt Library you want to play. Here is the link to the sound set editor: [link] (http://www.sibelius.com/download/sse/main.html). You end up generating an .xml file that tell Sibelius and the sound library how to talk to each other.

Answer (score 5):

Kontakt Player is a sample playback engine. It takes MIDI input from a sequencer and plays back from a chosen sample library. The player included with Sibelius is not meant to be used on its own--when you are using Sibelius with the included professional samples, Kontakt player is actually running in the background for playback. You won't see it unless you dig into the audio settings.

The full version of Kontakt player can be used with any sequencer program, not just Sibelius.